# AsserEquals not found in WebTestCase Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, web-testing

I have a WebTestCase class:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client;

class ApiAdminInvoiceControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        ...
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('id', $array);
        ...
    }
}
```

I have this error in all asserts:`Method 'assertArrayHasKey' not found`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase; as base class

Comment: But [`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.html) extends `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`, so why change the base class?

Comment: Ok. sorry did not notice. Than what is your phpunit version?